# Is it possible to change a css variable using js setProperty with a value of another js variable?

Tags: javascript, input, css-variables, setpropertyactionlistener

I have an input field, in which, user is supposed to enter the color of text, that he want's to be displayed later. I was wondering, if there is a way to change css variables with javascript setProperty function, and instead of a value, the argument would be another javascript variable?
for example:

```
elem.style.setProperty('--my-css-variable', anotherJsVariable);
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. `elem.style.color = anotherJsVariable` should do this

Comment: In your provided example, there is no need for css variables, right?

Comment: Did you try it before asking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just like you have.

Doing this is most of the point of CSS custom properties.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  const elem = document.getElementById("one");
  const anotherJsVariable = "yellow";
  elem.style.setProperty('--my-custom-property', anotherJsVariable);
}, 750);
```

```css
#one {
  --my-custom-property: red;
  background-color: var(--my-custom-property);
}

#two {
  background-color: white;
}

#three {
  background-color: var(--my-custom-property);
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
    <div id="three">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```